# Installing CDH on VMware - Cloudera-scm-server dies

Tags: hadoop, cloud, cloudera

I am trying to install CDH on VMware(Ubuntu 12.05 desktop) as per steps mentioned in below link:-
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_A.html.

I have found no issues till step 2, but everytime when I move ahead on step 3: cloudera-scm-server dies in backend, due to which I am unable to complete step 3. So when I see that cloudera Manager admin console gets stuck, i check the status of server on terminal by using below command and it shows that server is dead.

$user@ubuntu: sudo service cloudera-scm-server status

Checking for service cloudera-scm-server:  * cloudera-scm-server is dead and pid file exists

Please help me out, why server is getting dead after some time.

Comment: We need the log files for cloudera-scm-server in order to troubleshoot.  They can be found in:

`/var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log`
`/var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.out`